# How to duplicate a PHAsset?

Tags: ios, photokit, phasset

I am wondering how one could duplicate a `PHAsset` and preserve the photo's context. For example if the photo was located in a specific album, I want the duplicate to be located in that same album right next to the original. And if possible, the edit history would be preserved, allowing the user to revert that duplicate to the original if desired.

One could implement a share sheet and share the image, which would provide an option to save the image, but this isn't true duplication. Saving the image places it at the end of All Photos. If I create a new asset providing the image from my existing asset via `creationRequestForAssetFromImage`, that too is placed at the end of All Photos.

How can one programmatically duplicate a given `PHAsset`, preserving its location in the photos album hierarchy?

Comment: I am not totally sure what your asking but PHAsset does conform to NSCopying if all you want to do is make a copy?

Comment: @DBoyer That might be helpful! Once you have that copied PHAsset, how do you save it to their photo library though?

Answer (score 0):

From https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHAssetChangeRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014384-CH1-SW8

> To set metadata properties of the newly created asset, use the
>   corresponding properties of the change request (listed in Modifying
>   Assets). To reference the newly created asset later in the same change
>   block or after the change block completes, use the
>   placeholderForCreatedAsset property to retrieve a placeholder object.

Call `creationRequestForAssetFromImage` then set the appropriate meta data on a `PHAssetChangeRequest` using the `PHAsset` you want to copy.

```
let request = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromImage(image)
request.creationDate = copiedAsset.creationDate
request.location = copiedAsset.location
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this would simply save the photo to Camera Roll/All Photos. It wouldn't be located in the album the original asset was in, right? Note that it could even be in an album that's in a folder inside another folder, and I really need to keep this copy in that same location.